# Generating shapefiles from WKT format polygons using Arcpy?

Tags: arcpy, polygon, well-known-text

I am working with a database containing a geography field representing the Admin1 boundaries of countries. I would like to draw a map of the Admin1 boundaries of Somalia:

```
params = urllib.quote_plus(...)
engine = sqlalchemy.create_engine("mssql+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s" % params)
query = ("SELECT SimplifiedCoords.STAsText() FROM Adm1GeoBoundaries WHERE (Adm0Code = '226')")
df = pd.read_sql(query,engine)
```

this returns a list of the 18 subdivisions, e.g.:

```
0  POLYGON ((44.661 3.2516, 44.611 3.2715, 44.410...
1  POLYGON ((49.0611 9.571, 48.561 9.541, 48.061 ...
2  POLYGON ((44.2362 10.4724, 44.2021 10.5066, 44...
```

Each row is a pandas series instance.
My issue now is to convert these into json then shapefiles in order to map them (using arcpy). So far I have tried (I only focus on one polygon to test):

```
wkt = (df.loc[0]).to_string() # as loads() expects integer or string adress
g1 = loads(wkt)
```

But this throws : 
"ParseException: Expected number but encountered word: '44.410...'
and the Error is "ReadingError: Could not create geometry because of errors while reading input.".

I also tried the following:

```
sr = arcpy.SpatialReference(4326)
g1 = arcpy.FromWKT(wkt,sr)
```

But this has not led me anywhere yet.

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE! As a new user please take the [tour] to learn about our focused Q&A format.

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include a bit more of your code around the line `wkt = (df.loc[1]...` - what is it looking at, is it a list or dictionary  containing the values you show above?  Also what is your entire error message?

Comment: Are you able to present the data for a triangle located in Somalia, and a code snippet that applies your process to it successfully or otherwise?  I suggest using a triangle because three points should be something you can use to show us the data for an entire feature.